# STS project gives error cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

I am for the first time trying java in Spring Tool Suite and using an example project imported, now running into endless issues. I tried building the project and go the following error:

```
 Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/cccc/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-client/7.1.0/
 vaadin-client-7.1.0.jar' in project 'quicktickets-dashboard' cannot be read or is not a 
 valid ZIP   file   quicktickets-dashboard      Build path  Build Path Problem
```

This is probably a spring issue and not related to the project itself. Please does anyone have a working solution to this. Tried a few, building, closing, rebuilding, deleting local repository etc. but still the same issue. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your maven cache is corrupted.  First, check if the `C:/Users/cccc/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-client/7.1.0/vaadin-client-7.1.0.jar` jar is complete.  Run `jar tvf` on the file to make sure you can use it.

If you're lucky, things will work if you delete the `C:/Users/cccc/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-client/7.1.0/` folder, but if that doesn't work, you will have to try deleting `C:/Users/cccc/.m2/repository`. It's just a local cache of artifacts downloaded from maven central or an internal repository, so it is OK to delete.

I am 90% certain this would fix your problem.

Comment: thanks you were right. Deleting the entire folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I clear /.m2/repository/.cache and it works fine.